# What should I do to fix my logging output in playframework 2?

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, slf4j, logback

I am trying to do some debugging in the Controller level of my Playframework app:

```
Logger.debug("xxxxxxxxx");
```

Here is the default setting:

```
# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

Given the setting above I assume that I get some output from the debug logging. But I have to call `Logger.error()`, before I can see any output. [Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger) is the documentation concerning logging.

The root logger configuration affects all log calls, rather than requiring custom logging levels.

This means that no matter what level I set, everything is affected by the `logger.root` setting. Am I missing something? Is there a way to enable logging at debug level in my application without touching the `logger.root`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you also have a `conf/application-logger.xml` file and your application is running in production mode then your logger configuration in `application.conf` is ignored. I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug, but that's how it seems to work.